# A question about Euclidean spaces.

Tags: linear-algebra, euclidean-geometry

Let $\mathbb R^n$ be an Euclidean space with the natural metric, and let $V$ be a subspace such that 
\begin{equation}
 V\cap\{(x_1,\cdots,x_n)\colon x_i>0\;\forall i\}=\emptyset
\end{equation}
and 
\begin{equation}
 V\cap\{(x_1,\cdots,x_n)\colon x_i\geq0\;\forall i\}=\{(0,\cdots,0)\}
\end{equation}

Let $W=V^\perp$ and can someone help to prove 
\begin{equation}
 W\cap\{(x_1,\cdots,x_n)\colon x_i>0\;\forall i\}\ne\emptyset
\end{equation}

Thank you.

Comment: Try a low dimensional case first, to get a feeling for what's going on. Take $n=2$ and $V$ a line of negative slope through the origin. Are there vectors in the first quadrant which are perpendicular to $V?$ How would you show this? How can you generalize what you've done?

Comment: @ChrisLeary the cases in dimension 2 or 3 are easy, but I can not find a universal method to do this.

Comment: Let $X=\{(x_1,\dots,x_n):x_i\geq0\forall i\}$ and $Y=X\cup(-X)$. Can you show that any vector in $Y^c$ is orthogonal to a vector in $P=\{(x_1,\dots,x_n):x_i>0\forall i\}$?

Comment: @Display Name - Federico has a great hint to follow.